# How to custom condition compile and passing argument by cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to complie rust code with language option:

```
#[cfg(lang = "en")]
use xxx;

#[cfg(lang = "fr")]
use yyy;
```

and how to run cargo and passing argument ?

```
cargo release --feature "lang=en" // error!
```

Comment: you probably want `#[cfg(feature = "en")]` and `cargo release --features "en"`

Comment: that said I don't think a compile time language selection is advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#[cfg(en)]` and pass `--cfg en` to rustc.

But, if you use cargo, then you can append to your `.cargo/cargo.toml` (must create this file if you don't have) this:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["--cfg", "en"]
```

You can also make script to build and run a project that generates this file and invokes cargo.